# How to wait untill I get the results for HTTP get in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

```
export class PropertiesService {
 getCommonProperties():any{
        let URL: string = "/xxxx/yyyyy";
        let headers = new Headers();
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
        options.method = GET;
        return this.http.request(URL, options).map(response => {
            {
                console.log("response ", response.json());
                return response.json();
            };
    }
}

/**************************/
export class A {

this.commonProperties.setPropertiesMap(
this.propertiesService.getCommonProperties().subscribe(result => 
{ return result;})
);
//logic to iterate commonPropertiesMap
}
```

/*PropertiesMap is a map which stores a key value pair of some properties,I have a service named propertiesService where i get the stream of properties from the server, and i have to set the result into properties map. I am getting the result from server(i could see it in the console ) where as the control is passing to the next step even before i get the response from the server, so there is an error thrown that the PropertiesMap is not iterable. Can someone help me with the logic to hold the control until i get the result from HTTP request and set the values into the PropertiesMap and then iterate through the map??
*/

Comment: Put anything that relies on the result within the `subscribe` function, or a function that's called from within the subscribe function

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand could you please be more elaborate?

Comment: I've added an answer below. Im not entirely sure what the `setPropertiesMap` function expects, but you should get the general idea

Comment: Put your logic inside your subscribe that attains the result:
this.propertiesService.getCommonProperties().subscribe(result => 
//  Do stuff with result;
//logic to iterate commonPropertiesMap

}

)
);

Answer (score 1):

Put anything that relies on the result within the subscribe function, or a function that's called from within the subscribe function, like so:

```
this.propertiesService.getCommonProperties().subscribe(result => {
    // Do you logic that relies on the results within here
    this.commonProperties.setPropertiesMap(result);
    return result;
})
```

Comment: /*I have changed the code but no luck*/                                                        public getCommonProperties(): CommonProperties {
  if (this.commonProperties == null) {
   this.commonProperties = new commonProperties();
   this.propertiesService.getCommonProperties().subscribe(result => {
    this.commonProperties.commonPropertiesMap = result;
   });
   console.log("map", this.commonProperties.commonPropertiesMap);
  }
  return this.commonProperties;
 }

Comment: @tejasri Because the code is asynchronous, your return value will always be `undefined`.

Comment: got it thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the logic to iterate with in subscribe not outside

```
this.propertiesService.getCommonProperties().subscribe(result => 
this.commonProperties.setPropertiesMap();
//logic to iterate commonPropertiesMap
return result;
);
```